# Cannot convert type 'string' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IList<string>

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I keep gettig this error:

> "Cannot convert type 'string' to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IList"

Here is my program:

```
class Program
{


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {


        List<string> list = new List<string>(); 
        list.Add("a");
        list.Add("b");
        list.Add("c");
        list.Add("d");



        foreach (IList<string> name in list ) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{{{0} {1} {2}}}", list[0], list[1], list[2]));
```

Comment: What is your required output?

Comment: Is there anything else in your foreach loop? You've omitted the closing `}`.

Answer (score 4):

You have a list, and to that list you've added 4 strings. The list is a list-of-strings, not a a list-of-lists-of-strings.

I suspect you mean (since you are doing something with `.Format`)

```
List<string> list = new List<string>(); 
// 4 x Add
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{{{0} {1} {2}}}", list.ToArray()));
```

alternatively, if you mean the first 3 characters in each (which WON'T WORK for your sample data, since each is a string of length 1):

```
foreach(string name in list) {
    Console.WriteLine(
        string.Format("{{{0} {1} {2}}}", name[0], name[1], name[2]));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Change the `foreach (IList<string> name in list )` to `foreach (string name in list )`

The first token inside the foreach declaration is the type of the elements of the collection you are enumerating.

You can also use the `var` keyword to let the compiler figure out the type during compilation (while still getting benefits of static typing of the `name` variable): `foreach (var name in list)`

Answer (score 1):

in for each loop remove `IList<String>` and use `String`

```
 foreach(String name in list)
 {
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{{{0} {1} {2}}}", list[0], list[1], list[2]));
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your loop

```
foreach(string name in list)
{
    Console.WriteLine(name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Should you be doing this?

```
foreach (string name in list )
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the `list` contains`strings` not `IList<string>`

Either change the for loop to:

```
foreach (string name in list ) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine(name);
    }
```

or lose the `foreach` and just leave the `Console.Writeline` in there